# How can I normalize an attribute in Weka that has different meaning based in another attribute?

Tags: r, weka

So i have some data that looks like this:

```
year    gender  mark
2010      F      18
2011      M      25
2016      F      20
```

and i know that, prior to 2016, the max mark that a student could get was 25. In 2016, it was 20 instead.

What I've done is create a now column like that:

```
dataset$max_mark<-ifelse(dataset$year %in% (2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015),25,20)
```

And then used a simple fraction to calculate the normalized column:

```
dataset$normalized_mark<-dataset$mark/dataset$max_mark
```

How do I normalize the mark column with the prior statement into account in Weka or R? Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out: I had to use the `rescale` function from the `scales` library.
In my example I had marks from 0 to 25 that i had to rescale from 0 to 20. Assuming my original marks where in the array `marks`, the code was simply:

```
library('scales')
marks <- rescale(marks, c(0, 20), c(0,20))
```